# WordPress installation didn't install any default data and returned empty rows!

Tags: localhost, xampp

Here is how I stuck on the way of installing a fresh WP in my localhost.

I tried installing a fresh copy of WP in my localhost using WAMP server.

Everything is fine, like in the First step: I did input the Database name, the Username = "root", Password = "" Host = "localhost" and Table Prefix = "wcdev_" and then in the Second step I did input the Website Title, Username, Password and Email then click on Install WordPress.

After 5/6 seconds this window - http://prntscr.com/9ujqhl was come in front of me without let me gave the login option.

Then I looked on the database in my phpmyadmin panel and saw the weirdness - http://prntscr.com/9ujjkk all tables return Empty rows except the `wcdev_options` table and because there was no user install in the installation process so I failed t login also and the site url return me like this - http://prntscr.com/9uk3cv

Important Note: I tired the whole process both in WAMP and in XAMPP but the result remain same. I tried WordPress 4.4.1 and WordPress 4.3 version both to check in there is any version incompatibility.

Here is my XAMPP Server compatibility - http://prntscr.com/9uk7yl

Here is my WAMP Server compatibility - http://prntscr.com/9ukczy

Any solution?

Comment: The solution is here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18705561/installing-wordpress-on-wamp-gives-empty-tables-only

Answer (score 0):

What version of PHP are you using? This may be a problem with a lower version of PHP. Check your database user for privileges. Also check the php.ini file for `max_execution_time`, if might be at default value of 30, increase its value to 90 or more and then try again. Hope it helps.

Comment: I already got the answer here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18705561/installing-wordpress-on-wamp-gives-empty-tables-only

BTW, thanks for your support.